# Implicit casting letters in c++

Tags: c++, letters, implicit-conversion

Does this line

```
char chValue = max('a', '6'); // returns 'a'

int max(int nX, int nY)
{
return (nX > nY) ? nX : nY;
}
```

cast the letter `'a'` to its ASCII equivalent number then compare it to the integer?

Comment: Post the relevant code - what's the declaration of `max` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because `max` is a function that takes two `int`s as arguments, the char `a` will get [implicitly converted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) into an `int` and then get passed as an argument of the function.

Comment: Yup it takes 2 integers and returns the biggest , and thank's

Comment: @MekacherAnis glad I was able to help. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem/answered the question.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is an *explicit* conversion.

Comment: @KeithThompson noted, thanks. I meant that the implicit type conversion gets invoked. I now phrased this as "[...] implicitly converted [...]".

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly.

The character constants `'a'` and `'6'` are of type `char`, which is an integral type. They *already* denote integer values, and assuming an ASCII-based implementation, they denote the ASCII values of those characters. This is determined at compile time.

Your `max` function takes two `int` arguments and returns an `int` result. The `'a'` and `'6'` are *implicitly converted* from `char` to `int`. (This conversion yields a value with a different representation but the same value.) A cast is an *explicit* conversion, represented with a C-style cast operator (as in `(int)'a'`) or with one of the C++-specific cast operators (as in `static_cast<int>('a')`. Since `int` and `char` are both integral types, no cast is needed here.

(In C, character constants are of type `int`, and there wouldn't be any conversions at all.)

The `int` result returned by `max()` is then implicitly converted from `int` to `char`, and the result is stored in `chValue`.

C++ doesn't actually require characters to be encoded in ASCII.  For example, IBM mainframes use a different character set called [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). (In EBCDIC the comparison would go the other way, and `chValue` would be `'6'` rather than `'a'`.)